# Using request meta in Scrapy passes arguments in different order

Tags: python, callback, scrapy

Im' trying to scrape data from a page which has a listing of products, I'm currently getting all the links and scraping the details OK, but the problem is that the product manufacturer/brand is only in the listing page, not in the product page.
I've tried using passing request meta on the callback but the manufacturer data is passed unordered, resulting in the rows showing incorrect manufacturer.

This is the example page: https://www.toolmania.cl/sierras-sable-561

This is the code now:

```
    def parse(self, response):
    """Process toolmania.cl products"""
    # define product url xpath
    XPATH_PRODUCT_LINK = "//a[@class='thumbnail product-thumbnail']/@href"
    products = response.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_LINK).extract()
    XPATH_PRODUCT_BRAND = ".//h4[@class='product-manufacturer']/text()"

    for product in products:
        # obtain product brand
        brand = response.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_BRAND).get()
        #url = product
        yield scrapy.Request(product, callback=self.parse_product, meta={'brand': brand})

    # follow pagination link
    XPATH_NEXT_PAGE = "//li[@class='page-item directional js-search-link']//a[@rel='next']/@href"
    next_page = response.xpath(XPATH_NEXT_PAGE).get()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_product(self, response):
    """Get details from single product"""
    XPATH_SINGLE_PRODUCT = "//div[@class='single-product']"

    for product in response.xpath(XPATH_SINGLE_PRODUCT):
        # define xpaths for product details
        XPATH_PRODUCT_MODEL = ".//h5[@class='product-reference-single']/text()"
        XPATH_PRODUCT_NAME = ".//h1[@class='product-name-single mb-md-4']/text()"
        XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE = ".//div[@class='product-prices margin__bottom__20']//span[@itemprop='price']/@content"

        product_model = product.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_MODEL).get()
        # clean product model
        product_model = re.sub('Código de referencia: ', '', product_model)

        yield {
            'product_brand': response.meta['brand'],
            'product_model': product_model,
            'product_price': product.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE).extract(),
            'product_name': product.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_NAME).extract(),
            'product_link': response.url,
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `product` instead of `response` in the following loop, and also see I am using css instead of xpath

```
def parse(self, response):
    """Process toolmania.cl products"""
    products = response.css('div.product-list')

    for product in products:
        # use "product" instead of "response"
        brand = product.css('.product-manufacturer::text').get()
        url = product.css(".thumbnail::attr(href)").get()
        yield scrapy.Request(product, callback=self.parse_product, meta={'brand': brand})
```